# Replacing Strings in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I wanted to know how its possible to replace two chars in a string in MIPS Assembly. For e.g

```
   .data 
str:           "MIPS is love"
replacement:   "\n"
stringtoreplace: " "
```

I don't know where to start with this.

Comment: You start by thinking what the logic is and then writing that in asm

Comment: How do you iterate over a string in MIPS?

Comment: By writing a loop where you increment a register until some predetermined condition is met.

Answer (score 1):

Assume str is in $s0. Let $s1 be a iterator like your i in C. $s1 will be the offset to the base address stored at $s0. So in order to find and replace, you have iterate over the string by incrementing $s1.
let string to replace be in $s2 and replacement in $s3.

```
add $s1,$s1,$zero #initializing $s1 to 0
loop:
    add $t0,$s0,$s1
    lb $t1,0($t0)
    bne $t1,$s2,skip_replace
    sb $s3,0($t0)
    skip_replace:
    addi $s1,$s1,1
    bne $t1,$zero,loop
```

Answer (score -1):

Easy way for implementing functionalities in MIPS Asm,especially when it has to do with school projects is to begin with a C (or other low level prog. language) code to implement the functionality.
Then start to convert that to MIPS, as time passes by you will afterall be able to do it without the C part.